# Definição IsFirstRowAsColunmNames não existente no IExcelDataReader da referencia ExcelDataReader

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Usando o Visual Studio 2017, instalei os pacotes de referencia através do Nuget

- ExcelDataReader
- EcxelDataReader.DataSet versão 3.4.0

Estou seguindo um tutorial de como abrir arquivo XLS e esta dando erro na seguinte linha, gostaria de saber como faço para resolver este erro.

A linha que esta dando erro é esta no código abaixo:

**reader.IsFirstRowAsColunmNames = true;**

Diz que não contem esta definição no **IExcelDataReader**

Estou usando os seguinte using abaixo

- using ExcelDataReader;
- using System;
- using System.Data;
- using System.IO;
- using System.Windows.Forms;

  ```
  private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      DataSet result;

      using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() {Filter="Excel Workbook *.xls", ValidateNames = true })
      {
          if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
          {
              FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
              IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
              reader.IsFirstRowAsColunmNames = true;
              result = reader.AsDataSet();
              cbbPlanilha.Items.Clear();

              foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
              {
                  cbbPlanilha.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
              }

              reader.Close();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Não tem esse método, por isso do problema, talvez seja algo relacionado com a versão, ou não tem mesmo no tutorial qual é a versão do `ExcelDataReader`???

Comment: A versão do ExcelDataReader é a 3.4.0

Comment: Não tem esse método! não existe

Answer (score -1):

Depois de instalar o pacote "ExcelDataReader" pelo NuGet basta incluir a biblioteca:

using Excel;

A partir daí a biblioteca ExcelDataReader não será mais necessária.

Caso tenha problemas mesmo assim, tente mudar a versão do ExcelDataReader (a versão 2.1.2.3 funcionou para mim)

Consegui esta solução no site abaixo. Seguindo as instruções lá funciona:
(https://foxlearn.com/article/how-to-read-excel-file-in-csharp-159.html